# Trying to use Boost C++ Library on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I've been trying for hours to get [Boost](https://www.boost.org) C++ libraries working on MacOS 10.13.6.

I'm up-to-date with Xcode and Homebrew.

I used `brew install boost` to install boost and followed the [Boost Getting Started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) instructions for help with compiling.

I've tried everything that I can think of and read every post I can find on StackOverflow about this.

I'm attempting to compile with:

`g++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -I /usr/local/opt/boost/include -L /usr/local/opt/boost/lib ass3.cpp -o ass3 -lboost_filesystem`

and I get the following error message:

```html
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "boost::system::detail::generic_category_ncx()", referenced from: boost::system::generic_category()
in ass3-3dc386.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I haven't yet tried to install Boost from source.

If I exclude `-std=c++17` the code will compile with a warning that I am using c++11 alias. As I get further into my project I'll be using c++17 specific features so I need to include this as far I as I know.

Compiler warning:

`warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you remove -std=c++17, you compiler (clang) would definitely use c++98 so clang will warn you since some lines of your program are using a c++11 extension.

Comment: For the linking error, you should append `-lboost_system` to your compile directive. If that doesn't work, it may be another linking library in boost (I don't know its name either, so search google for more info). However, it has nothing to do with compiling boost from source, so don't waste time on it.

Comment: @tigertang that's it! Now that you point it out, I see it in the error message. I don't  understand why that is necessary but that fixed it. Thanks!